# How to keep test reference data in a separate store?

Tags: python, unit-testing, datastore

I'm writing tests in python with `unittest` library, I have several test enviroments with different test data.

- What is the best way to store test reference data (I don't want to put them into 'test*.py' files)?
- Is there any good way to store in special format (input values to call methods, output values to compare with) ?

Any ideas?

Comment: Andrew, I have edited a bit. Do you expect to have "input data" AND "expected results" in the data store?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a decorator that does data retrieval from your custom store and passes it on to the actual test function. I've done this in past:

**Decorator**

```
from functools import wraps

def data_provider(fn_dp):
  def test_decorator(fn_test):
    @wraps(fn_test)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwds):
      for data in fn_dp():
        try:
          fn_test(self, **data)
        except AssertionError, e:
          raise(AssertionError('{0} - [{1}]'.format(e, data)))
    return wrapper
  return test_decorator
```

Now i can write my unittests like this:

```
data = lambda: (
  {
    'input': '1234',
    'expected_op': '1234'
  },
  {
    'input': '1234',
    'expected_op': '1234'
  }
)

@helper.data_provider(data)
def test_something(self, input, expected_op):
  self.assertEqual(input, expected_op)
```

Now the decorator will call the test function for all data points.

For your specific case take a look at `fn_test(self, **data)` in `data_provider`. Instead of `**data` you can read from your custom storage and call the test function from here.

Comment: I need idea how to organize data store. i.e.: I need to fill 2 inputs(I have ids), click button and check results (table)

Answer (score 0):

My solution next:
I have a storage class, witch get test data from json files, before each test (called in setUp method):

```
def setUp(self):
    self.data = self.storage.getDataFor(self._testMethodName) 

def test_ftu_02_003(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.data['title'], self.page.get_title())
    self.assertEqual(self.data['header'], self.page.get_header())
```

and sample json file example, json filename is same as py file name:

```
{
"test_ftu_02_003":{
    "title":"example_title",
    "header":"example_title"
    }  
}
```

so I can change path to folder with files for each enviroment, and it's easy to rewrite json file from python code.

Question: And what about output data?
Answer: All data is input data (it go to input to assert*)